# Find unknown variable in set of equations in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have six equations and six variables. I am solving it through `numpy` using  `np.linalg.solve(a, b)`. The result gives me 6 values but I don't know which value is x1,x2... unknown variable result satisfies only one equation that is

```
                          x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6=1.
```

but it does not satisfies other equation. I am considering that x[0] is x1. x[1] is x2 but which is not true because other equation not satisfies when I put according to this format. How can I find which is x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 in returning list? My code is

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[-1,0,0,0.25,1,0.33], [0.33,-1,0,0,0,0.33], [0.33,0.25,-1,0.25,0,0] , [0,0.25,0.5,-1,0,0], [0,0.25,0.5,0.25,-1,0.33], [1,1,1,1,1,1]])
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print x
```

answer is:

```
[ 0.2644666   0.13780854  0.14895903  0.10893165  0.18669913  0.15313504]
```

Comment: Do proper formatting please.

Comment: thanks. actually i did not know how to do formating. by the way thanks

Comment: Why do you say it does not satisfy the other equations? I'd say you're wrong there.

Comment: I have put value in other equation

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong or interpreting it wrong. Check my answer below.

Comment: there is no issue with the float values i put values in equation x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6=1. sum of list is 1 which means it is correct but when i put in equation (-1) x1 + (0) x2+ (0) x3+( 0.25) x4+ (1) x5+ (0.33) x6=0 considering that x[0] is x1, x[1] is x2 and so own....

Comment: Yes, and `b[0] = 0`.. so what else are you expecting? It's the solution you asked for.

Comment: I just want to know that which index s x1 value and which value is x2 and so own...

Comment: x[0] == x1 and so on

Comment: i have tried this : 
eq_1 = (-1 * x[0]) + (.25 * x[3]) + x[4] + (0.33 * x[5] )
print eq_1

Comment: it shoud be zero according to equation

Comment: but answer is 2.77555756156e-17

Comment: And it is! Which number do you get instead? Exactly, will you please see my answer and the referred link please. You have a problem understanding float point arithmetic.

Comment: i did not understand that question. can you please tell me just that it is zero or not???

Comment: For the computer 2.77555756156e-17 is basically 0. Because of how floating point works that's the level of precision you have.

Comment: if i ma not wront that answer mean this value is very very small and we consider it zero beacuse  2.77555756156e-17 is equal to 0.000000000000000027755 which means zero....???

Comment: ok thank you very much . I have spoiled much time to solve understand the hardware problem . actually that is not problem that is a level of precision.:)

Comment: thanks for your assistance

Comment: At last! ;) Mark the answer as accepted then ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
for i in range(6):
    (a[i]*x).sum()
```

You'll get that the first five elements are of the order of e-17 (basically 0 in float representation) and the last one is 1 as specified by the `b` vector you provided.

I believe your problem is not understanding the issues concerning float arithmetic. You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more information.